# How to equally subdivide a closed CGPath?

Tags: uikit, core-animation, core-graphics, polygon, cgpath

I've an indeterminate number of closed `CGPath` elements of various shapes and sizes all containing a single concave bezier curve, like the red and blue shapes in the diagram below.

What is the simplest and most efficient method of dividing these shapes into `n` regions of (roughly) equal size?

[image: Current CAShapeLayers]

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: My app divides the screen into a number of regions (closed CGPaths) similar in shape to the diagram above. As the user moves their finger around each area, I need to display a different value. Potential values for a given area are defined by a third-party API and change frequently, so I need to equally subdivide each region as the view loads. I can then map those sub-divisions to the API values and, as touches are tracked, check what specific path contains the current touch point/ value to select.

Comment: FYI, I considered some form of tessellation, incl. Voronoi with Lloyds clustering, but couldn't find (or come up with) any way to do this in a performant manner on an iOS device. In my case, each region needs to support up to 500 sub-divisions, and there are 6 regions on screen at any one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation). [Here is an example](http://nodename.com/wpEmbeds/VoronoiToy/bin/PlanePointsApp.swf) which resembles what you want to do. It uses an [as3 library](http://nodename.github.io/as3delaunay/). Here is an iOS port, that should help you:

https://github.com/czgarrett/delaunay-ios

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I came across Chris Garrett's port some time ago, but performance of that (or any Voronoi implementation I could come up with) simply isn't good enough on an iOS device. In my case, each region needs to support up to 500 sub-divisions, and there are 6 regions on screen at any one time.

I guess I'm asking: is there a "simpler" and "more efficient" way of solving this problem?

Comment: Hmm. What happens with your current implementation when you run it? I mean are you cpu limited or gpu limited? Do you have some performance stats? What's the lowest number of subdivisions that run at a performance level that is acceptable? What's your targeted iOS device?

Comment: On an iPhone 5, the best I can do with Chris Garrett's port is about 80 points in a second on the GPU using SceneKit (e.g. https://github.com/sam-keene/iOSSpriteKitDelaunayTriangulation). https://github.com/mrotondo/Edgy is better, but at 200 points it's taking 2/3 of a second to add a new one and 1/3 of a second to calculate the corresponding Voronoi area (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ios9fyladnidoag/Screenshot%202014-03-26%2011.01.55.png).

Comment: The other challenge I have with all of these solutions is making the subdivisions uniform and equal. That said, I guess there is no silver bullet; some Delaunay variant is probably the best solution (hence, the bounty award).

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. A Delaunay variant is probably your best bet. Also I looked at the performance and it seems like you might be cpu limited. Have you considered implementing custom shaders and moving a bunch of the calculation there? That should be a huge performance boost. If you are willing to share your xcodeproject, I can look into it and have more pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the context of what you want to achieve and what the constraints are. For instance, is there a hard requirement that the subdivided regions are equal size?

Often the solutions to a performance problem is not a faster algorithm but a different approach, usually one or more of the following:

1. Pre-compute the values, or compute as much as possible offline. Say by using another server API which is able to do the subdivision offline and cache the results for multiple clients. You could serve the post-computed result as a bitmap where each colour indexes into the table of values you want to display. Looking up the value would be a simple matter of indexing the pixel at the touch position.
2. Simplify or approximate a solution. Would a grid sub-division be accurate enough? At 500 x 6 = 3000 subdivisions, you only have about 51 square points for each region, that's a region of around 7x7 points. At that size the user isn't going to notice if the region is perfectly accurate. You may need to end up aggregating adjacent regions anyway due to touch resolution.
3. Progressive refinement. You often don't need to compute the entire algorithm up front. Very often algorithms run in discrete (often symmetrical) units, meaning you're often re-using the information from previous steps. You could compute just the first step up front, and then use a background thread to progressively fill in the rest of the detail. You could also defer final calculation until the the touch occurs. A delay of up to a second is still tolerable at that point, or in the worst case you can display an animation while the calculation is in progress.

You could use some hybrid approach, and possibly compute one or two levels using Delaunay triangulation, and then using a simple, fast triangular sub-division for two more levels.

Depending on the required accuracy, and if discreet samples are not required, the final levels could be approximated using a weighted average between the points of the triangle, i.e., if the touch is halfway between two points, pick the average value between them.

Comment: Great feedback thanks. I think you're right: given the low level of accuracy required, in my case a hybrid approach of both Delaunay and regular subdivision might work. Given the original question is phrased, Æ's answer will probably get the bounty, but I wanted to let you know your input was very useful!